# How to automatically call a function before "kill-emacs" by mouse?

Tags: emacs, elisp, exit, quit

I need to call "my-global-modified-flag-update" function before closing Emacs (C-x C-c). 
This function marks as unmodified the buffers that I don't need to save, thus avoiding Emacs to ask me for.
Of course it must run as first task, before Emacs asks me about save files.

This is my easy solution for keyboard command "C-x C-c" (save-buffers-kill-terminal)

```
(defun my-kill-emacs()
   (interactive)
   (my-global-modified-flag-update)
   (save-buffers-kill-terminal))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'my-kill-emacs)
```

How to do the same when closing Emacs by mouse? (clicking on the windows top right X)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option I can think of, if hooks are not enough for you, would be to advice `save-buffers-kill-emacs`.

Try this:

```
(defadvice save-buffers-kill-emacs (before update-mod-flag activate)
    (my-global-modified-flag-update))
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine! And furthermore it works for all Emacs Quit sources (keyboard, mouse and menu).

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it that way at all.  Just use `kill-emacs-hook` or `kill-emacs-query-functions`.  See the Elisp manual, node `Killing Emacs`.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I have added some more information in my question.
I have followed you indication but without lucky. The problem is that "kill-emacs-hook" and "kill-emacs-query-functions" don't call my function as first task but after Emacs asks me about save file. Too late.

Comment: Right. Then do this: `(setq confirm-emacs 'my-global-modified-flag-update)`.  The function that is the value of `confirm-emacs` just needs to be a predicate that accepts at least one arg. If it returns `nil` then Emacs is not exited; else it is.  E.g.: `(defun my-blah (__) (message "Howdy!") (sleep-for 3) t)` `(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'my-blah)`